# .htaccess из php в html

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, сервер

Как в .htaccess прописать замену .php и параметров на .html, таким образом, чтобы передавались GET параметры. (Из `site.ru/index.php?param=1&param1=2&...` в `site.ru/param_1/param1_2...` .html) Такое возможно? Не обязательно именно так - любой вариант нужен чтобы .html получить и параметры передавались.

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы просто заменить `.php` на `.html` достаточно в `.htaccess` написать следующее:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

Только проверьте чтобы у вас в `Apache` был включен модуль `mod_rewrite`

Comment: Вопрос, разумеется, не в этом.